# Trouble getting columns to line up in my table

Tags: html

I've been trying to fix this table for awhile now and I'm having a lot of trouble getting my columns to line up correctly. I've attached the picture below so you can see what I mean. Can someone please point out what I'm missing here.

[image]

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="4" class="border-bottom-0 pt-0 pb-0"></th>
         <th colspan="7" class="border-bottom-0 pt-0 pb-0"><small>Schedule</small> </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th class="border-left border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">#</th>
         <th class="border-left-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">Last name</th>
         <th class="border-left-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">First name</th>
         <th class="border-left-0 border-top-0 border-right pt-0">Room</th>
         <th class="border-left border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">Mon</th>
         <th class="border-left-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">Tue</th>
         <th class="border-left-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">Wed</th>
         <th class="border-left-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">Thu</th>
         <th class="border-left-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">Fri</th>
         <th class="border-left-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">Sat</th>
         <th class="border-left-0 border-top-0 border-right pt-0">Sun</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="border-left aling-double-row">1</th>
         <td>Brown</td>
         <td>Angela</td>
         <td class="p-0" colspan="8">
            <table style="width: 100%;">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="border-0">Koala</td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="monday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="wednesday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="thursday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="friday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="saturday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="sunday"></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <table style="width: 100%;">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="border-0">Possum</td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="monday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="wednesday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="thursday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="friday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="saturday"></td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="sunday"></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why nested tables? you should specify each width of the cell to keep it lined up.

Comment: I nested the table because react complains if you have a <td><tr><td></td></tr></td>.   Error message is `<tr> cannot appear as a child of <td>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested tables aren't the best choice for this view. Use `rowspan` for the first 3 columns. The code will look like this.

```
<tr>
    <th class="border-left aling-double-row" rowspan=2>1</th>
    <td rowspan=2>Brown</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Angela</td>
    <td class="border-0">Koala</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="monday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="wednesday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="thursday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="friday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="saturday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="sunday"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="border-0">Possum</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="monday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="wednesday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="thursday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="friday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="saturday"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="sunday"></td>
</tr>
```

Notice that the first 3 columns have the `rowspan` value 2. It will take 2 rows. In the next row, you don't need to create the first 3 columns.